# EJS and DUST - side by side

Tags: node.js, ejs, dust.js

I am using node.js  with express and ejs.

I should move my site from ejs to another template engine - dust.js. I want to be able to move the templates from one template engine to another one by one. The problem I see is that both override the res.render method.

The solution I can think about is to store the res.render `var render_ejs = res.render;` after the ejs is required but before the dust.js is required. Then after the dust.js required - to store the new render but under a different name `res.render_dust = res.render` and override the render with the ejs ones again `res.render = dust.render`.

What is the right way to make them to live side by side?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example on how to use two engines side-by-side (I'm using Jade because Dust gave me some grief about `require.paths`):

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express);
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // Render with Jade: res.render('index.jade');
  // Render with EJS: res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.listen(3012);
```

So the trick is to use the file extension in `render()`, which combined with `app.engine` will make Express use the appropriate templating engine.

Comment: To resolve the require.paths issue with express 3+ and dust you need to move from dust to dustjs-linkedn.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @robertklep.

Finally `consolidate` (node.js template engine consolidation library) solves my problem.

Here is a working example:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var express = require("express");
var app = express.createServer();
var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin'),
    cons = require('consolidate');
app.engine('dust', cons.dust);
app.get("/dust", function(req, res) {
    res.render('dust_template.dust', {header: 'DUST - TEST OK'});
});
app.get("/ejs", function(req, res) {
    res.render('ejs_template.ejs', {header: 'EJS - TEST OK'});
});
app.listen(80);
```

The `ejs_template.ejs` and `dust_template.dust` files are in the `views` folder.